# How does the casule construct an api url?

Tags: api, url, search, sample, bixby

I modified the perfect cartoon sample and I guess I'm having trouble understanding how the api URL is constructed from the capsule.  I uploaded my attempt on github here: https://github.com/igotapochahontas/skynet

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the query object in options for URL parameters. Example code:

```
  var options = { 
    query: {
      day: day
      cam: cam
    }
  };
```

if they are set or using modifying your code:

```
  if (typeof(day)!= "undefined"){
    options.query.day= day
  }
```

A great source for example code that does things like this is the [Bixby Github](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers) In particular, look at the http-api-calls example at https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection

See also the docs at: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http#http-options